# extjs6 pivot sort by aggregate column not working

Tags: extjs, pivot

In my extjs6 pivot grid, how do I auto sort by aggregate column?  I tried putting direction in the aggregate section with no luck.  any suggestions?

I want to sort by totalPL

```
                                    title: 'Portfolio',
                                xtype: 'pivotgrid',
                                itemId: 'pivotGridId',
                                cls: 'custom-gridPivot2',
                                //ui: 'featuredpanel-framed',
                                matrix: {
                                    viewLayoutType: 'outline'
                                },
                                startRowGroupsCollapsed: false,
                                multiSelect: true,
                                enableLocking: false,
                                viewConfig: {
                                    trackOver: true,
                                    stripeRows: true
                                },
                                bind: {
                                    store: '{myDailyAttributionBreakdownStore}'
                                },
                                aggregate: [{
                                    dataIndex: 'totalPL',
                                    header: 'TotalP&L',
                                    aggregator: 'sum',
                                    renderer: 'renderFormatCurrency',
                                    align: 'right',
                                    width: 100,
                                    direction: 'ASC'
                                }],
                                leftAxis: [
                                    {
                                        width: 75,
                                        dataIndex: 'sector',
                                        header: 'Sector'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        width: 100,
                                        dataIndex: 'shortDesc',
                                        header: 'Market'
                                    }
                                ],
                                topAxis: [
                                ]
```